# How can I create a Web-service to share data from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, export

Our organization has an externally hosted website that displays data from a monitoring system. Data is currently provided by FTPing csv files.

The data is stored in a SQL Server Database. The exported data sets are only a few hundred rows of data, updated hourly.

I would like to replace this with a a web service so that data can be retrieved on demand, and we avoid handling files.

I'm a DBA not a programmer, so i'm out of my comfort zone. Is there a conventional approach for doing this? Are there standard Microsoft products that we could configure to achieve this? Or do we need to hire a programmer to develop something custom from scratch?

I know SSIS can consume data from a web-service but can it provide data as a web-service?

Comment: There aren't any exactly like this in current versions of SQL, and I haven't seen anything about hosting your own web service in PowerShell.

You'll either need a programmer or be comfortable enough with programming to do it. If you have Visual Studio you'd probably start with looking at Lightswitch; it is a quick way to start up a UI to a database, however also exposes everything you do as a web service in the process. It still requires work to get it going though.